# Customer user cannot create chatter post on a community group

Tags: apex, chatter, customer-community, feeditem, connect-api

I have an issue when I try create a post from an apex class, the user is a customer community user and I create the post from a Lightning community

```
ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(Network.getNetworkId() , '0F96E000000D1InSAK' ,  ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem , postChatter);
```

The above line of code throw an excpetion 'System.NoAccessException - Class.ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement'. The user is correctly added to the community group, any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the settings 'Only Broadcast' in the group, if it's checked the customer user cannot post in the group

Comment: Is it all your passing in your payload? To post feeds, there are two to three required fields like type, parent id etc .. did you already enabled feed for whichever object you are posting to?

Comment: I'm posting on a private group, but I have already fix unchecking the setting Only Broadcast in the group, thanks anyway